# Can i Print to a dell 3010cn from Snow Lepoard

Tags: printing

i have a dell 3010cn printer, and a iMac

having some trouble getting it installed, i know that its not officially supported but i installed foomatic-rip and ghostscript and downloaded the pxldpl PPD file but i wont actually print though it can connect to the printer

the printer is connected to my LAN

Comment: Can you print if you connect locally?

Comment: havent tried that, maybe, but its in another room so its not a practical option, but i could try it just for kicks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve success.
On my Ubuntu box I got it to print over wifi, 
And on the mac I could print through the Ubuntu Box as a print server.
I used the windows box I have as a server and it worked. No control of any options though. 
 Never Could print directly though.

Answer (score 0):

[This Dell driver](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R144508&SystemID=PRN_LSR_3110CN&os=MAC1&osl=en&deviceid=9510&devlib=0&typecnt=1&vercnt=2&formatcnt=1&libid=40&fileid=192663) is for the 3110cn. Maybe it will work?

As you can see from the [Google discussions results](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=3010cn+mac), many people have tried without success.

Sorry to say, it looks like this isn't possible possible over the LAN.

A Mac should be able to print to almost any printer connected by USB, with or without specific drivers.

Answer (score 0):

May be relevant:
http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-precision/2007-March/001130.html

From link:

> I had to issue a retraction last week,
>   as I discovered the 3010CN does not in
>   fact have a PostScript engine in it,
>   but a Windows GDI engine for which I'm
>   not aware of CUPS drivers.

No postscript engine likely means its a non-starter for Lin & Mac. Sorry.